# Remote desktop FROM a WinCE 6.0 TO big Windows

Tags: windows-ce, remote-desktop

I have a Windows Embedded CE 6.0 Device that I want to use to remote IN to a big Windows client. Is there any tool/app/utility that would basically make the CE device a Remote server and connect to a big windows client?

Thanks
Rishi

Answer (score 1):

Sure, contact the OEM and have the RDP client included as part of the OS image.

Comment: I have the RDP client included as a part of the OS, but that just sucks. I was looking for an alternative. I just want to use my WinCE device as an external "display" of sorts.

Comment: What about the RDP client is not doing what you want?  You don't want to have to launch the client to connect (which could be done with an autorun executable at startup) or something else more fundamental?

Comment: I need to get *almost* realtime updates from the host screen on the WinCE screen, maybe even look at a video playing on the host screen. I am not sure if its the hardware that's limiting me, but right now, I can only log in and then do some basic operations such as creating and editing a text file or browsing the file system. Otherwise, the whole device hangs up on me. 

My question is: is there a better way in which I could look at updates from the host screen on the WinCE screen? 

Thanks